# Multiple drag-selections in PhpStorm 8

Tags: phpstorm, text-editor, behavior

I've just transitioned from Sublime Text (3) to PhpStorm (8) and I love that it now has the multi-caret feature.

It kills me though that there is no option to multiple drag-select. If you try, it will just increment your first selection (at least if you changed <kbd>alt</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>).

Is there a way to modify/add this behavior?

Comment: I need this feature too.